# Updating JSON data stored in a CLOB in Db2

Tags: sql, db2, clob

I want to perform an update to JSON data stored in a CLOB column in a Db2 table.

For instance, a section of of the CLOB data currently looks like this

```
 "commercialOfferPersonRoleList" : [ {
          "commercialOfferPersonRolePK" : {
            "commercialOfferId" : 100000000008817
          },
          "personId" : {
            "personID" : "1000019579"
          }
         },
         "roleBusinessPartner" : {
          "value" : 1
        }
       ]
```

and after update, I want it to look like this

```
"commercialOfferPersonRoleList" : [ {
              "commercialOfferPersonRolePK" : {
                "commercialOfferId" : 100000000008817
              },
              "personId" : {
                "personID" : "1000019579"
              },
              "roleBusinessPartner" : {
              "value" : 1
               }
             }
            ]
```

When our application is hit, values are populated in respective tags and this CLOB value gets stored in a table. Due to some changes I need to update the COLB values for almost 10k records in a similar fashion.

Is there a way of writing a generic script to implement such kind of change?

I have used xquery to update XML structure before, but here we need to change the position of the tag along with the respective valum, and this time it is JSON data

just to simplify, my objective is :

```
before Update :

                            commercialOfferPersonRolePK
                                         |
               ----------------------------------------------------
               |                                                  |
    -----------------------------                            roleBusinessPartner
    |                           |
    commercialOfferId         personId
```

after update :

```
  commercialOfferPersonRolePK
           |                                                  
----------------------------------------------------------                            
|                           |                            |
commercialOfferId         personId                   roleBusinessPartner
```

Comment: What do you mean by "generic script"? The missing `}` means that the before value is not valid XML, so you won't be able to use XML functions on it. If you had used an `XML` datatype for the column, the invalid data would not have been allowed in the first place. What is the total length of your CLOB values, and what version of DB2 are you using, those will affect which functions you can use to update the CLOB.

Comment: The example i have given is just a section of xml and not the entire xml itself.

Comment: The attribute has been defined like : DATA_OBJECT  CLOB(1048576) INLINE LENGTH 164 NOT NULL. We are using DB2 V10.5

Comment: what is it's actual max used length. E.g `SELECT MAX(LENGTH(DATA_OBJECT_CLOB)) FROM table`

Comment: 567515 is the max length

Comment: OK, so you can use `REPLACE` as the length is less than 1,048,576 bytes. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000843.html

Comment: Is the data valid JSON data? What version of Db2 are you using?

Answer (score 1):

For JSON data, as of Db2 11.1.3.3 use `SYSTOOLS.JSON_UPDATE` to update JSON values

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.json.doc/doc/r0070292.html

You will need to covert the data to BSON with `SYSTOOLS.JSONTOBSON` and then back again with `SYSTOOLS.BSONTOJOSN` after the update

E.g. something like this

```
values 
  SYSTOOLS.BSON2JSON(
    SYSTOOLS.JSON_UPDATE(
      SYSTOOLS.JSON2BSON(
    '{ "commercialOfferPersonRoleList" : 
        [ 
            {    "commercialOfferPersonRolePK" : { "commercialOfferId" : 100000000008817 } 
             ,   "personId" : {  "personID" : "1000019579" } 
            }
        ,   {"roleBusinessPartner" : { "value" : 1 } }
        ]
     }')
     , '{ $set:
      { "commercialOfferPersonRoleList" : 
        [ 
            {"commercialOfferPersonRolePK" : { "commercialOfferId" : 100000000008817  } }
        ,   {"personId" : {  "personID" : "1000019579" } }
        ,   {"roleBusinessPartner" : { "value" : 1 } }
        ]
     }
     }'
     ))
```

Comment: Thanks for your input Vernon! However i have 10k such clob values to update, hence it will be cumbersome to write a query for each of these clob. The tags and structure are same in all the clobs but their respective values are different.Is there any generic solution that can help me update multiple records at once.We will be using a timestamp attribute to identify the set of target records.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of regex might solve your problem..  depends on how complex your full problem is...  e.g.

```
create table clob(c clob(1M))
;                  
insert into clob values ('{ "commercialOfferPersonRoleList" : 
            [ 
                {"commercialOfferPersonRolePK" : { "commercialOfferId" : 100000000008817  } 
            ,   "personId" : {  "personID" : "1000019579" } }
            ,   {"roleBusinessPartner" : { "value" : 1 } }
            ]
         }')
      ;   
select regexp_replace(c,'(,\s*)("personId"(.*?\}){1}?)\s*\}', '} \1 { \2 }', 1, 0, 'n') from clob;
```

which returns

```
{ "commercialOfferPersonRoleList" : 
            [ 
                {"commercialOfferPersonRolePK" : { "commercialOfferId" : 100000000008817  } 
            } ,    { "personId" : {  "personID" : "1000019579" } }
            ,   {"roleBusinessPartner" : { "value" : 1 } }
            ]
         }
```

So you could do, e.g.

```
update clob set c = regexp_replace(c,'(,\s*)("personId"(.*?\}){1}?)\s*\}', '} \1 { \2 }',1,0,'n')
              where regexp_like   (c,'(,\s*)("personId"(.*?\}){1}?)\s*\}'               ,1  ,'n');
```

I suggest you use `SYSTOOLS.JSON2BSON` to check that the transformed blob is still valid JSON before you actually run the update.

in this example, I can run this to check the updated column is still valid JSON

```
select SYSTOOLS.BSON2JSON(SYSTOOLS.JSON2BSON(c)) from clob
```